# Adding new functionality to a class

Tags: c++, qt, class, overriding, derived-class

I'm studying the Qt4 library and I want to add some functionality to **all the children of `QWidget`** in my project. I need all widgets to have `mousePressEvent` overridden. Obviously I do not need to override it in every particular widget I use(I use **many** of them and I they to follow DRY rule) , instead I create a `Foo` class:

```
class Foo : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    protected:

        /* implementation is just a test */
        virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*) { this->move(0,0);  }
};
```

And derive my button from it:

```
class FooButton : public QPushButton , public Foo
{

    public:
        FooButton (QWidget* parent) : QPushButton(parent) { };

};
```

But the event seems to be not overridden... What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are doing smth wrong! You shouldn't face this problem. Why do you need to change behavior of _all_ widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inheriting twice now from QWidget. This is problematic (see [diamond problem](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/diamond-problem)).

Instead, drop your `Foo` class and move your custom mouse press event handler to your `FooButton` class:

```
class FooButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:

    /* implementation is just a test */
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*) { this->move(0,0);  }

public:
    FooButton (QWidget* parent) : QPushButton(parent) { };

};
```

If this doesn't suit the design of your application, then try using virtual inheritance instead. That is, change `Foo` to:

```
class Foo : public virtual QWidget
```

If that doesn't help, you should follow the advice of the other answers and install an event handler.

(You can read about virtual inheritance in its [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).)

Comment: I will need to drop it to add it to all types of widgets in my project... Many types of widgets.... There must be another way to solve this...

Comment: @Kolyunya Try with virtual inheritance instead. I updated the answer.

Comment: Virtual inheritance will not work here because `QAbstractButton` does not inherit virtually from `QWidget`.

Answer (score 2):

For the mousePressEvent access, try QObject::installEventFilter().

http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qobject.html

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is that you're inheriting from `QWidget` twice, once through `QPushButton` and once through Foo.

From the way you phrased the question, I'm assuming that you want to do this for varying kinds of widgets, and thus don't want to have to subclass QPushButton, QLabel, QCheckBox, etc. If this is not the case then you should use Nikos's answer.

If not, your best bet is probably doing to be to use an [event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter).

```
class MousePressFilter : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MousePressFilter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) { }

    protected:
        bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) {
            QWidget *widget = dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(watched);
            widget->move(0,0);
            return false;
        }
};
```

And then in your Foo class constructor:

```
class Foo {
    Foo() {
        installEventFilter( new MousePressFilter(this) );
    }
};
```

Comment: I have many different widgets in the project and ALL of the must have this event overridden. I don't think copying reimplementation of the event in every particular class is a good idea (DRY, you know...). I know nothing about event filters yet, thank, gonna learn about it...

Comment: I've implemented your advise. When I derive QWidget both from some widget and from Foo, the event filter doesn't work for some reason... Any ideas...

Comment: Sorry I made a bit of a mistake, Foo shouldn't inherit from anything. Part of your problem was that you were inheriting from two classes that were both `QObject`s, which is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, but `Foo` will have `installEventFilter` only if it's a child of `QObject`, right? Seems, this is an unsolvable problem.

Comment: Oh yeah. Duh. The best I can think off at the moment is to add that line of code to each of your widgets. Not ideal, but at least it's just one line of code.